# Python 2 + Python 3 + library

Tags: python

I have both Python 2 and 3 in the same machine and installed a library (requests) through my package manager. I am only able to import it in Python 2, is it meant to be like that? If not how can I import it in Python 3?

Comment: Install the Python 3 version of the library. Usually it's named `python-requests` or maybe `python3-requests`.

Comment: Yes, it's meant to be like that.  A package created for one version of Python does not necessarily work with other versions of Python.

Answer (score 4):

Each python installation on your machine has its own separate set of packages installed. So to use `requests` with both pythons you need to install it twice, once for each version. It could be exactly the same library (and its distribution) for both pythons not some "python 3 version".

The most convenient way to do it is to have separate `pip`s for your pythons. On Debian-like Linux (including Ubuntu) you can get them by:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python3-pip
```

There could be other command in other Linux flavors, just look for `pip` in your packages. You can try using `brew` on Mac OS X and google "installing pip for python 3 on windows" on Microsoft OS. Either way you should get two executables `pip` and `pip3` an then:

```
pip install requests
pip3 install requests
# prepend these with sudo if needed
```

You can also install packages without `pip`. However, it's more tedious: download source and unpack, `cd` in, install it with following commands:

```
python setup.py install
python3 setup.py install
```

Comment: Debian is slightly peculiar in that they break out `pip` into a separate package. Most other places, if you have Python, you also have `pip` as part of that install already (though this won't be true for older versions of Python 2; but you should absolutely not be using anything older than 2.7 anyway).

Comment: Going forward, as more and more projects drop support for Python 2, you are increasingly likely to find that only old or even obsolete versions of libraries are available for Python 2, if at all.