# Python 3 not working with NLTK 3

Tags: python, nltk

I just updated to Python3... well, sort of. I can run both Python2.7.9 in the terminal and Python3. I also have NLTK3, which usually works with Python2.7, but there are some times when certain things don't work. Yet when I switch to Python3 in the MacOSX terminal, it won't let me import nltk (or anything else for that matter). Is there a simple fix for this?

```
>>> python 3
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: no module named 'nltk'
```

Comment: There is no Python 2.9. Python 2.7 is the last version of the Python 2 series. Do you mean Python 2.7.9?

Comment: Yes. Typo. Thank you, I will correct that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Libraries don't carry over between python versions.

You need to install that library for python 3 too.

[Python 2 + Python 3 + library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075333/python-2-python-3-library)

Answer (score 7):

On Mac OS X:

```
# Install pip
$ curl bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
$ curl bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3
```

On Ubuntu:

```
# Install pip
$ sudo apt-get install pip
$ sudo apt-get install pip3
```

Then:

```
# Install NLTK on python and python3
$ sudo pip install -U nltk
$ sudo pip3 install -U nltk
# Install Numpy
$ sudo pip install -U numpy
$ sudo pip3 install -U numpy
$ python
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('all')
```

Comment: Additionally, I needed to restart my terminal after doing steps 1 and 2 to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you!! I wish I could give this a few more upvotes.